# ¿Cómo puedo modificar un registro desde php?

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es que no me modifica el registro cuando envió el formulario.
utilice var_dump() para ver que me retornaba la variable donde almaceno la consulta y me retorna false, no se que pueda estar pasando.
Este es el codigo:

```php
<?php

include('conexion.php');

$usu = $_POST['usu'];
$n_nombre = $_POST['n_nombre'];
$n_apellido = $_POST['n_apellido'];
$n_correo = $_POST['n_correo'];
$n_pass = $_POST['n_pass'];


$consulta ="UPDATE usuario SET nombre='$n_nombre', apellidos ='$n_apellido' correo='$n_correo' contraseña='$n_pass' WHERE nombre='$usu'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

if ($resultado>0) {

    echo"Modificado";
}else{

    echo"error"; 
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pongas la llamada de mysqli_query dentro de un bloque try/catch para ver qué error puede estar dándote. Así a primeras el mysqli_query tiene los parámetros al revés. Primero es la consulta y luego la conexión. Revisa https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Está bien el orden de mysqli_query, lo que veo es que no tienes comas en los campos a modificar en la consulta excepto entre nombre y apellidos, es el error que detectó hasta el momento.

Comment: gracias, ya pude soucionarlo